# Getting error on inserting date into sql database?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, oledb

I'm inserting record into database but is getting error on the paremeter "Date". Any thoughts would be good.

```
myConnection.Open()
Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO MasterLabNumber (LabNumber, Location, Date)" + "VALUES(@LabNumber, @Location, @Date)"
Dim str As String
str = "SELECT * FROM MasterLabNumber WHERE (LabNumber = " & TextBox1.Text & ")"
Dim d As System.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myConnection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LabNumber", TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", ComboBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", d)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() <-- gets error here relating to adding the parameter date.
```

Comment: Try `Dim d As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
`

Comment: You arent inserting a date but a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's cause `Date` is a reserve word which you are using in your insert statement. You need to escape it like below using `[]`

```
INSERT INTO MasterLabNumber (LabNumber, Location, [Date])
```

Your insert statement should become

```
Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO MasterLabNumber (LabNumber, Location, [Date]) VALUES(@LabNumber, @Location, @Date)"
```